# How to add "Area (square kilometres): Integer," to my schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have been working on this for awhile now. Can't seem to get this to accept and not turn into a function.
I am creating a schema for my mongoDb that will be connected to my Apollo Express Server with GraphQL.
The Question: How would adding "Area (square kilometres): Integer," look inside a schema without it being turned into a function?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const {Schema} = mongoose;

export const albainiaStatsSchema = new Schema({
 Country: String,
 Year: String,
 Area (square kilometres): Integer,
})
```

Dataset:

```
[

 {

   "Country": "Albania",

   "Year": "2000",

   "Area (square kilometres)": 28748,

   "Total population": 3401198

 },

 {

   "Country": "Albania",

   "Year": "2001",

   "Area (square kilometres)": 28748,

   "Total population": 3073734

 },

 {

   "Country": "Albania",

   "Year": "2002",

   "Area (square kilometres)": 28748,

   "Total population": 3093465

 },

 {

   "Country": "Albania",

   "Year": "2003",

   "Area (square kilometres)": 28748,

   "Total population": 3111162

 }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add the property name with quotes, similarly to how it appears in your dataset:

`'Area (square kilometres)': Integer`